# Read configuration from a specific file - Web.config or appsettings.json based on the calling web application

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core

I have a monolith project and I'm trying to convert one Web Application from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core with Full Framework.
As you can see from the figure, both Web Applications are referencing Class Library 3. CL3 contains Business Logic but also logic about how to read specific configuration (till now from Web.config file).

Since the way to read configuration has changed in ASP.NET Core (appsettings.json Environment based) I have to rewrite the part that reads the configuration from CL3.

Is it possible a scenario like this?

```
#IF CALLED FROM ASP.NET
    RETRIEVE CONFIGURATION FROM WEB.CONFIG
#ELSE (CALLED FROM ASP.NET CORE FULL FRAMEWORK)
    RETRIEVE CONFIGURATION FROM APPSETTINGS.JSON
```

[image: Project dependencies]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are refactoring, try to move configuration reads out of the shared DLLs and provide a clean abstraction that does not have hidden dependencies on framework-specific assets.

Your ASP.NET Core Application and classic ASP.NET Applications could create a config based on their config system (you could provide two different config implementations) and then use your CL3's classes and pass in configuration objects.

Alternatively, you could use a `ConfigurationBuilder` to read AppSettings and connection strings from appsettings.json and appsettings.{Environment}.json and make it available through the classic `ConfigurationManager` API. See [this blog post](https://dasmulli.blog/2017/01/21/use-appsettings-json-and-environment-overrides-in-classic-asp-net-apps/) for details on how to do this. This can be extended to configuring custom configuration sections (classic .NET) from json files.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Regarding your blog post, Worker Roles are accessing settings with RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue instead of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings for example. Also, what happens when we want to overwrite the endpoint of a WCF service? Web.config has an endpoint while Web.Preproduction.config has another endoint (there aren't in appSettings sections). Do you think this can be overcomed by the method described in your blog?

Comment: I don't think classic WCF endpoints are supposed to be configured via appsettings.json files, this method would only be useful for the intersection of configuration values that are accessed from both asp.net core and classic ConfigurationManager. If the configuration or APIs are specific to classic .NET Framework settings. You can still access classic .config configuration from ASP.NET Core apps if they are running on .NET Framework.

Comment: Using the method from your blog post, from clasic ASP.NET application you access the appSettings/connectionStrings using ConfigurationManager. Can you do the same in a ASP.NET Core application? If so, how you can register the AppSettingsJsonConfigurationBuilder as the default builder for the configuration?

Comment: ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework can also use an App.config file to put configuration into, this is where you'll want to register it. Since the ASP.NET Core hosting model involves launching the app as a sub-process (at the moment), it won't get web.config configuration, but should read from an App.config

Comment: Just to be sure we are pointing in the same direction. If we have a clean ASP.NET Core Full Framework application with appsettings.json, can ConfigurationManager.AppSettings read from it without problems? I do not want App.config to come into play. Just apsettings.json from ASP.NET Core Full Framework.